# Publish post on Wordpress with REST API and Java Jersey application

Tags: java, wordpress, rest, jersey

I'm trying to publish a post on a Wordpress site by using a Jersey WebResource object. Both Wordpress site and Java application are local. I'm trying this:

```
    String url = "http://localhost:81/testsite/wp-json/wp/v2/posts";
    String myPostData = "{'title':'test','content':'bla bla bla'}";

    Client client = Client.create();
    WebResource webResource = client.resource(url);
    webResource.header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "Basic XXXXXX"); //XXXXXX is the encoded user:password
    webResource.header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json");
    webResource.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

    ClientResponse response = webResource.post(ClientResponse.class, myPostData);
```

I'm getting the response:

> POST http://localhost:81/testsite/wp-json/wp/v2/posts returned a response status of 401 Unauthorized

When using Postman, I'm able to publish sucessfully.

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: _"XXXXXX is the encoded user:password"_ - How are you encoding it? And can you post an image of successful Postman request.

Comment: I just copy the value of the Authorization key on Postman and paste on my Java code, just for test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WebResource.header()` returns a new `WebResource.Builder`. So when you are doing

```java
WebResource webResource = client.resource(url);
webResource.header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "Basic XXXXXX");
```

in the second line, you are creating a new `WebResource.Builder` and doing nothing with it. So what is happening is the headers never get set as you are calling `post()` on the original `WebResource` and not the `WebResource.Builder` that you set the header on.

You can either assign the `header()` call to a `WebResource.Builder` variable and call methods on *that*, or you can just chain the calls.

```java
WebResource webResource = client.resource(url);
WebResource.Builder builder = webResource.header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "Basic XXXXXX");
builder.header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json");
builder.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
ClientResponse response = builder.post(ClientResponse.class, myPostData);
```

Or chain it all

```java
ClientResponse response = client.resource(url)
        .header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "Basic XXXXXX")
        .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json")
        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .post(ClientResponse.class, myPostData);
```